# Getting the max values from JSON in D3

Tags: javascript, json, scale, d3.js

I'm using D3 with JSON data with a function similar to this:

```
 d3.json("http://api.json", function(jsondata) {
 var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.number; });
```

This causes data to equal `["2", "5", "8", "12"]`

Then if I use:
`var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data)])`

The max returned is 8 instead of 12.  I realize this is because 8 is greater than 1 in 12, but I'm not sure how to fix this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the API reference, [d3.max](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_max) returns the maximum value using **natural order**. Since you are computing the maximum of an array of strings, [lexicographic (alphabetical) order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) is used. Compare:

```
console.log("8" > "12"); // true
console.log(8 > 12); // false
```

If you want to compute the numeric maximum of an array, you should probably convert those strings to numbers first. A convenient way of doing that is the unary `+` operator:

```
var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return +d.number; });
```

If you prefer, you can also use parseFloat, parseInt, Number or a variety of other methods to coerce strings to numbers. Technically, you could do this as part of the d3.max call (`d3.max(data, Number)`), but it’s generally faster and safer to do the coercion explicitly.

Of course, since you’re already using JSON and JSON is a typed serialization format, it might also make more sense to store numbers in JSON rather than strings; then you won’t need any type coercion.

Comment: Thank you Mike.  That is a very helpful answer.  Thank you for creating D3 - I just started learning it and I'm loving it.